# Working with an API which return a xml not patterned

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, express, xml2js

I am requesting an API sending to it words to be searched then retrieving the data from the API. Unfortunately the xml tree is not patterned, so I need to parse the xml file for each word with **if** statement.
like so:

```
    if((JSON.stringify(result["entry_list"]["entry"][0]["sound"][0]["wav"][0])) !== undefined) {
        ...
        ...
       }
```

I need to check if there are those elements in the xml, otherwise I will have an error saying: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

The problems is that with that **if** I am not having success, so I would like to know what is the right way to lead with that situation?

Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf3HS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HeSV.png)

Comment: show example of the xml that returned

Comment: Please provide the response so we can help with your statement

Comment: @Sag1v I attached two print screens so I think they can show what is going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [object-get](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-get) so that it will not throw error if the path is not there.

```
const objectGet = require('object-get')

const colour = objectGet(mammal, 'fur.appearance.colour')
const text = objectGet(el, 'children[2].children[1].children[1].textContent')
```

and just check like `if (text) {}`